# Protractor test opening browser in root folder of XAMPP

Tags: angularjs, testing, npm, protractor

So I'm trying to run and end-to-end test as described on the Angular site:

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03

Now when I run `npm run protractor` in git bash, everything runs fine except when the browser opens to run the test, it opens in the root folder of XAMPP and not in the folder I currently testing in.

How to make this end-to-end test work?

This is how I run the test:

[image]

This is what my git looks like after I run the command:

[image]

And this is what the browser opens:

[image]

As you can see, the browser location indicates it is testing from the root but I think it should be loading from the folder I am currently in (see Git bash).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please show us your protractor.config file and also mention what url you expect to launch in browser.

Comment: Where do I find this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you need to change the base url located in the protractor-conf.js file. The file is located in the same project folder where you installed protractor. There you will finda folder called 'test' and there you will find a file called '`protractor-conf.js`'. You will need to adjust the `baseUrl` to the right path so that your protractor test will open the browser with the right path.

[image]